# Как сделать бесконечный реконект к серверу?

Tags: java

Кто-нибудь подскажет, как сделать бесконечный реконнект к серверу, пока он не зайдет на сервер?
Я делал так, если сервер вырубается, Клиент ловит Exception, там я делаю булевую переменную, типо нет подключения. Обращаюсь к классу reconnect, если он не ловит exception, то подключается к серверу и работает дальше, а если снова exception, то класс снова вызывает себя. Но почему-то не получилось. Кто подскажет, как сделать?

```
public void reconnect() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Переподключение сокета.");
        s.close();
        s = new Socket(IP, SERVER_PORT);
        is = s.getInputStream();
        os = s.getOutputStream();
        run();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        SocketInputThread.test=false;
        reconnect();
        System.out.println("Невозможно подключиться к сокету " + IP);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public void reconnect()` это как я понял не класс а функция, Вам как нужно Класс или функция?. И что делает `run()` ?? может по результату `reconnet()` будете вызывать `run()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если функция reconnect() только создает соединение. Может этот метод Вам поможет

```
public boolean reconnect() {
    boolean connected = false;
    while (!connected) {
        System.out.println("Переподключение сокета.");
        try { // Если вдруг пременное s нулевое
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            s = new Socket(IP, SERVER_PORT);
            is = s.getInputStream();
            os = s.getOutputStream();
            connected = true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            connected = false;
            System.out.println("Невозможно подключиться к сокету " + IP);
        }

        if (!connected) { // Предлогаю дать 1 сек задержку между соединениями
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
    return connected;
}
```

при использовании можете сделать так

```
if(reconnct()) run();
```

я убрал `run()` из кода `reconnect()`

Answer (score -2):

Если я правильно понял ,то можно сделать через таймер и запустить его ,и вызывать твой метод (в таймере пока ты его не остановишь) ,и когда ты успешно подключился к серверу то останавливать таймер (сделать условие на его выключение) ,а если нет подключения то таймер пусть и работает.

Comment: Извините, конечно, но вместо советов (некомпетентных) потратьте свое время на изучение матчасти. Больше пользы будет!